# CPU running at 99-100% while idle

Tags: power, desktop-computer

I am currently fixing a computer for my neighbor and it is running at 100% cpu power while idle. Is this normal? If not, how can I combat this issue? I never have this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a CPU running at 99-100% while idle and was told to check all users in processes. I checked and I currently have the following running at pretty high memory.

```
svchost.exe, SYSTEM, 143,000 K (Host process for Windows services) &

TrustedInstaller.exe, SYSTEM, 275K (Windows Modules Installer)
```

Are these vital to the OS or can I end the process? I'm sure that is what is slowing down the CPU

Comment: It's definitely not normal. There's definitely a background process running, that should not be. Could you provide us with more information from the task manager to see if it shows what process is eating up the CPU?

Comment: attach a screenshot of task manager > all tabs

Comment: Try uninstalling Avast antivirus. If that doesn't work, see which services are actually running and disable anything non standard. The list above shows services but not sorted by which are actually running, it could be an issue with a third party service.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal configuration, only loading services and process absolutely required to function, does this behavior happen?

Comment: Like Safe Mode?

Comment: You may want to check that box "Show processes from all users". There could be something like the Search Indexer or antivirus software running in the background.

Comment: Would clearing the physical memory cache help at all?

Comment: @AndrewMorton +1. I had this same issue, and that fixed it for me. For me it was a Windows Update service.

Comment: So I showed process from all users and have 2 big applications running. svchost.exe which is at 158,400K and Windows Modules Installer running at 275k - are those both vital or can I end the process on them?

Comment: Please update the screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that windows is downloading/installing updates in the background of your computer. Based on the way your task manager looks, i'd say you're running windows 7.

You can tackle this problem in a number of ways. But here are my two simple suggestions.

1. Leave your computer alone until the process is finished downloading and install updates. And windows will notify you that you need to eventually restart the computer.
2. Go To control panel > Windows update > change settings (left panel). Under important updates select the option check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them or Download updates but let me choose whether to install them.

Doing both of these suggestions should allow windows to update this time around. And give you more control the next time around when there is another update that needs to be installed. So you actually know whats going on and why your CPU usage is so high.